# Can I use diesel to convert table-per-type database tables to a Rust enum?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

My current database schema looks like this:

[image: ER Diagram]

The diagram represents data for a karaoke player. The song table holds the metadata of a given song. And each song has different types of media associated to it. `CDG` and `LCR` are two media formats for karaoke song files.

Different media formats require different amounts of files. And different file types. I modeled this by using different tables.

To map the media to a song, I use a junction table. It's primary key is the `song_id` and the `media_type`. `media_type` denotes the table where the `media_id` comes from.

My question is: how can I build a query using `diesel` that fetches the song alongside the correct media struct? Best-case would be an enum like this:

```
struct MediaModel {
    Cdg(CdgModelStruct),
    Lcr(LcrModelStruct),
}

struct SongWithMedia {
    song: SongModel,
    media: MediaModel,
}
```

Is this possible? I don't know how to map the fact that a song can have one of multiple media types assigned to it into Rust.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would need to do the mapping to enum yourself after loading it as a row of joined tables like `Song, SongMedia, Option<CdgMediaFile>, Option<LcrMediaFile>`.

Comment: That should not be a problem. However, I am already struggling with loading the models together that way. Is it possible to do this without having to manually do two separate queries? 

Because as it is now, I can query the song, then check the `media_type` value and query again. I'd like to do this in a single query (if possible).